# searching a file and counting

Tags: python, file, list, counting

I have a list of lines from a txt document that i have opened.

```
list = ['hello there','how are you','im good thanks']
```

Im looking to search through this list to see if the word 'hello' appears in it and then count the number of times it appears in there.  Apart from this i have opened the text file into a list then split it by spaces e.g.

```
list = ['hello','there','how','are','you','im','good','thanks']
```

would this be a better method to use before trying to look through the list for 'hello' and count it, if so how would i do this?

Comment: Does the name "Othello" contain the word "hello" or not?

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Added `line.split()` in case Othello is in the document. Also `line.lower()` handles uppercase 'Hello'

```
>>> lines = ['hello there','how are you','im good thanks']
>>> sum(line.lower().split().count('hello') for line in lines)
1
```

You could just do this straight from the file like:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    sum(line.lower().split().count('hello') for line in f)
```

Answer (score 0):

With your second method, you could just go

```
list.count("hello")
```